# Recommendation with optimization

Tags: java, optimization

How can I achieve more optimization in following code?, I don't like my last check "Objects.isNull" ?  Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Tries to get the service request DAO from the ItemHolder, if it is not present there, it will try to get it from the argument.
 * If no service request found then CancellationException is thrown.
 *
 * In case both are present takes precedence the one in the ItemHolder object.
 *
 * @param itemHolderParameter the holder to be checked.
 * @param serviceRequestDAO in case no service request dao is found in the holder, this will be used.
 * @return ServiceRequestDAO guaranteed not null object.
 * @throws CancellationException in case no service request DAO was retrieved.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case itemHolderParameter is null.
 */
public static ServiceRequestDAO getServiceRequestDAO(final ItemHolder itemHolderParameter, final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO){


    AtomicReference<ServiceRequestDAO> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(serviceRequestDAO);
    final ItemHolder itemHolder = Optional.ofNullable(itemHolderParameter).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("ItemHolder must not be null"));
    Optional.ofNullable(itemHolder.getServiceRequestDAO()).ifPresent(atomicReference::set);


    //Final validation.
    final ServiceRequestDAO requestDAO = atomicReference.get();
    if(Objects.isNull(requestDAO)){
        throw new CancellationException("Unable to get ServiceRequestDAO (null)");
    }
    return requestDAO;

}
```

~M

Comment: Well, last if can be rewritten to:
        return Optional.ofNullable(atomicReference.get()).orElseThrow(() -> new CancellationException("Unable to get ServiceRequestDAO (null)"));

Comment: Does anyone could have more ideas?

Comment: I don’t like any of it. Abusing an advanced concurrency construct to work around the “effectively `final`” requirement is **always** a sign of something very wrong. Why are you unwrapping an `Optional` using `ifPresent` only to later check for `null` and throw? This is completely degenerate.

Comment: If your code is working and you are just looking for it to be improved, this might be a better question to post on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). And what exactly do you dislike about the current code? Is it not readable? Not efficient?

Comment: `return Optional.ofNullable(itemHolderParameter).map(ItemHolder::getServiceRequestDAO).orElseThrow(() -> new CancellationException("Unable to get ServiceRequestDAO (null)"))`. Delete the rest.

Comment: ah thank yoi @Wrokar, I did not know exists a code review stack exchange

Comment: Well here we have 3 situations and all its combinations: holder (null/not null), service request inside holder (null, not null) and another service request when the one in holder is null and this could be as well be null.

Comment: The `map` covers those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Boris,

```
 /**
 * Tries to get the service request DAO from the ItemHolder, if it is not present there, it will try to get it from the argument.
 * If no service request found then CancellationException is thrown.
 *
 * In case both are present takes precedence the one in the ItemHolder object.
 *
 * @param itemHolderParameter the holder to be checked.
 * @param serviceRequestDAO in case no service request dao is found in the holder, this will be used.
 * @return ServiceRequestDAO guaranteed not null object.
 * @throws CancellationException in case no service request DAO was retrieved.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case itemHolderParameter is null.
 */
public static ServiceRequestDAO getServiceRequestDAO(final ItemHolder itemHolderParameter, final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO){
    return Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable(itemHolderParameter).map(ItemHolder::getServiceRequestDAO).orElse(serviceRequestDAO)).orElseThrow(() -> new CancellationException("No service request could be retrieved."));
}
```

The test cases:

```
public class HolderUtilsTest {


@Test(expected = CancellationException.class)
public void testHolderParameterNulls(){
    HolderUtils.getServiceRequestDAO(null, null);
}

@Test(expected = CancellationException.class)
public void testHolderParameterHolderNull(){
    HolderUtils.getServiceRequestDAO(new ItemHolder.Builder().build(), null);
}


@Test
public void testHolderParameterNullAndSRNotNull(){
    final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO = Mockito.spy(new ServiceRequestDAO());
    final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO1 = HolderUtils.getServiceRequestDAO(new ItemHolder.Builder().build(), serviceRequestDAO);
    assertThat(serviceRequestDAO1).isNotNull();
    assertThat(serviceRequestDAO1).isEqualTo(serviceRequestDAO);
}


@Test
public void testHolderParameterNotNullWithObjectAndSRNull(){
    final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO = Mockito.spy(new ServiceRequestDAO());
    final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO1 = HolderUtils.getServiceRequestDAO(new ItemHolder.Builder().srDao(serviceRequestDAO).build(), null);
    assertThat(serviceRequestDAO1).isNotNull();
    assertThat(serviceRequestDAO1).isEqualTo(serviceRequestDAO);

}

@Test
public void testHolderBothPresent(){

    final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO0 = Mockito.spy(new ServiceRequestDAO());
    final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAO1 = Mockito.spy(new ServiceRequestDAO());
    final ServiceRequestDAO serviceRequestDAOResult = HolderUtils.getServiceRequestDAO(new ItemHolder.Builder().srDao(serviceRequestDAO0).build(), serviceRequestDAO1);
    assertThat(serviceRequestDAOResult).isNotNull();
    assertThat(serviceRequestDAOResult).isEqualTo(serviceRequestDAO0);
    assertThat(serviceRequestDAOResult).isNotEqualTo(serviceRequestDAO1);


}
```

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable` - what now? [`Optional.or`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) would make more sense here.

Comment: Yes because the parameter could be null, but in the meantime I modified the code to get rid of that parameter, so at the end is how you described it in the first place, but my statements was still valid as it is composing functions

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no good reason to bring `Optional` or `AtomicReference` into it:

```
if (itemHolderParameter == null) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(...)
}
ServiceRequestDao dao = itemHolder.getServiceRequestDAO();
if (dao != null) {
  return dao;
}
if (serviceRequestDao != null) {
  return serviceRequestDao;
}
throw new CancellableException(...);
```

I have done my best to follow the semantics of your code, but honestly, it is very unclear.